# compilation unresolved external symbol gdcm::system::getHostName etc

Tags: c++, libraries, itk

I am making a c++ project using ITK (via the .lib of itk).
on qmake, I make the link with ITK libraries like that:
in the .pri:

```
MyITK {
CONFIG_FOUND += MyITK
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $${PACKAGE_LIB}/MyITK
win32:LIBS += ITKBiasCorrection-4.13.lib \
ITKIOImageBase-4.13.lib \
ITKNrrdIO-4.13.lib \
itkgdcmMSFF-4.13.lib
etc \
```

and in the .pro:
`CONFIG += MyITK`

the link with itk seems to work but I have a compilation error:

`LINK2019 unresolved external symbol gdcm::system::getHostName`
[image: error message]
after research it seems that it could be linked to the fact that I should add in qmake the libs: 
    `Snmpapi.lib Ws2_32.lib Rpcrt4.lib and psapi.lib`
but I don't know where to find them. I don't find them on my computer.

I am working on windows 7, using visual studio 2015.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [WinSDK 8.1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=323507) or later. All of the said files are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib\winv6.3\um\x64\`on my computer.